# make a ajax call to node js and get some data from it

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, runtime-error, response

I am fairly new to Node JS so may be I am asking a too broad/poor question, but pardon me for it.
 I have been trying to call a nodejs function through AJAX Jquery and then want to show data returned from nodejs on my view but I am always ending up in error block. This is my code, if anyone could guide me through this?

index.jade(Client)

```
extends layout

block content
    body
        head
            script(src=' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')

        h1= title
        p Welcome to #{title}
        a(href='' onClick="myFunction1()") Test
        script.
           var myFunction1=function(){
                var url = './checkUser1';
                var message = {userName: "XYZ"};
                var dataType = 'application/json';
                $.ajax({
                    url: './checkUser1',
                    data: '{"data": "TEST"}',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: dataType,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        console.log('Success: '+ret)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
                    },
                });
            }
```

index.js

```
router.get('/checkUser1', function(req, res) {
res.send({'data': 'some data is coming up'});

});
```

Now what I want is once I get response from this function I want to print a alertbox dispplaying this data

```
{'data': 'some data is coming up'}
```

Any idea what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the URL you're hitting:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './checkUser1',
  data: '{"data": "TEST"}',
```

The period shouldn't be there.  Switch it to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/checkUser1',
  data: '{"data": "TEST"}',
```

Comment: Hi, I tried ur approach but its not working, I am able to reach upto nodejs function but I am not able to throw back some data from nodejs function and to use it in ajax jquery

Comment: is ti because of same origin policy?

Comment: @Maverick yeah it could be same origin policy try this res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
and then send your data